# MLCP aggregated XML

Tags: xml, marklogic, mlcp

I try to load aggregated XML files using MLCP into ML8.

This is my data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<export:batch xmlns:export="http://schemas.dikw.nl/exporter/1.0" xmlns="http://schemas.dikw.nl/export/1.0">
   <cdm:BerichtInhoud xmlns:cdm="http://schemas.dikw.nl/data/1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.dikw.nl/data.xsd">
      <cdm:berichtMetaData>
         <cdm:Bericht>first message</cdm:Bericht>
      </cdm:berichtMetaData>
   </cdm:BerichtInhoud>
   <cdm:BerichtInhoud xmlns:cdm="http://schemas.dikw.nl/data/1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.dikw.nl/data.xsd">
      <cdm:berichtMetaData>
         <cdm:Bericht>second message</cdm:Bericht>
      </cdm:berichtMetaData>
   </cdm:BerichtInhoud>
</export:batch>
```

And this is the mlcp command I use:

```
mlcp.sh import \
 -host localhost \
 -port 27041 \
 -username admin \
 -password admin \
 -input_file_path ../sampledata/thijstest \
 -input_file_type aggregates \
 -aggregate_record_element BerichtInhoud \
 -aggregate_uri_id berichtId \
 -output_uri_prefix /sample/thijstest/ \
 -mode local
```

The result on the command-line is this:

```
15/09/10 10:23:51 INFO contentpump.ContentPump: Hadoop library version: 2.6.0
15/09/10 10:23:51 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: Content type: XML
15/09/10 10:23:51 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
15/09/10 10:23:51 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner:  completed 100%
15/09/10 10:23:51 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: com.marklogic.contentpump.ContentPumpStats: 
15/09/10 10:23:51 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: ATTEMPTED_INPUT_RECORD_COUNT: 0
15/09/10 10:23:51 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: SKIPPED_INPUT_RECORD_COUNT: 0
15/09/10 10:23:51 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: Total execution time: 0 sec
```

So I conclude that the element 'BerichtInhoud' is not found, I have tried to include the namespace like -aggregate_record_element cmd:BerichtInhoud.

Maybe it has something to do with this 'bug', although it's from january.
[Loading data with mlcp - namespace issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27911554/loading-data-with-mlcp-namespace-issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to use this for the namespace:

```
-aggregate_record_namespace "http://schemas.dikw.nl/cdm/1.2" \
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer to the question -- that takes it off the "unanswered" list.